# Why are two universal objects isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory

Browsing some [old online notes](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~virk/notes/pre08/pdf/categories.pdf), it is claimed that two universal objects are isomorphic because they admit the identity morphism on themselves. But from two identity morphisms, how would you get an isomorphism between the two?

Comment: From “a universal object admits the identity morphism on itself” follows another theorem “every endomorphism on every universal object $A$ is equal to $id_A$”. The latter theorem is used in the theorem which you ask about. The proof in those notes is just too scarce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be two universal objects. The universal property gives a unique map $A \to B$ compatible with the universal property, and also a unique map $B \to A$ compatible with the universal property. The compositions of these maps in both orders are necessarily $\text{id}_A, \text{id}_B$, again by the universal property.

**Edit:** Some remarks are in order. It is not true that a universal object only has trivial automorphisms in the parent category. What is true is that a universal object only has a trivial automorphism compatible with the extra data that comes from being a universal object. For example, if $A$ is the product of objects $X, Y$, this extra data is the pair of projection maps $A \to X, A \to Y$.

Comment: Perhaps for a beginner, it is worth noting that the defn of universal object also entails that the only _automorphism_ of it respecting other properties is the identity map. This then implies that the two composites @Qiauchu Y. mentions truly must be the respective identities.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: IMHO your remark is clearly contradicting category theory. :) To resolve this confusion, we should *name categories*. Every morphism belongs to some category. In case of the product, we consider a category C of 2-sources into $X, Y$. Your “extra data” are actually a part of the object in C. And in C every terminal object *in fact only has the trivial automorphism*. And there may be other automorphisms, but in Set, not in C.

Comment: @beroal: noted. I'll be more precise about what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

For a universal property we can build a category within which the universal object is the initial one. The usual properties of initial objects give the isomorphism you've asked for.

**aside**:I've never been impressed by the nomenclature *universal* property, a better one would be a *characteristic* property, this already carries with it the idea that all objects satisfying the characteristic property are isomorphic because they are *characterised* by it.